# How can "Textview" get the amount "Edittext" gets in AlertDialog?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-edittext, textview, android-alertdialog

I'm a java beginner and I've been thinking how
    to deal with this problem all day i wanna my `TextView` money get the
    number `EditText` gets in `AlertDialog`, what should i do?

```
package com.example.user123.income;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Income extends AppCompatActivity implements
        AdapterView.OnClickListener,
        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener,
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener,DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{

    final java.util.Calendar c= java.util.Calendar.getInstance();

    TextView date,money;
    ImageButton food,drinks,transport,games,housing,medical,pet,others;
    EditText edit,view;
    AlertDialog entermoney;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_income);

        date=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.date);
        date.setOnClickListener(this);
        date.setText(c.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"/"+(c.get(Calendar.MONTH))+1+"/"+c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        money=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.money);

        food=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.food);
        drinks=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.drinks);
        transport=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.transport);
        games=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.games);
        housing=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.housing);
        medical=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.medical);
        pet=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.pets);
        others=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.others);

        edit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit);

        entermoney=new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Enter the amount")
                //.setMessage("???")
                .setPositiveButton("OK",null)
                .show();


    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v==date){
            new DatePickerDialog(this,this,
                    c.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                    c.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It will help you [this](https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-prompt-user-input-dialog-example/)

Comment: Store in instance variable,After closing popup,use `money.setText("Value u got from edittext dialog);`